# Plupload getting js size value in $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

Looked for about 2hours but couldn't find a solution. I want to get the value of the file.size which is calculated by plupload and put into my database via php $_POST. Is this possible? As you will see below I have tried using the jQuery .text function but this doesn't work.

**Js code:**

```
if ($('#uploader').length)
{
    var text_val = $('#uploader_filelist .plupload_file_size').text(); //preferred

    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        url : '?do=' + _do + '&flag=upload&id=' + _id,
        chunk_size : '100kb',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        //resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
        multipart_params : {
            "name1" : text_val,
            "name2" : "value2"
        },
        unique_names : true,
        preinit: attachCallbacks,
        filters : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}]
    });

    var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response)
    {
        var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response.response);
        $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + " class='img'><img src='/media/images/galleries/" + _id +"/" + responseObj.filename + "' /><b>" + responseObj.filename + "</b>(" + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ") <span></span></div>");
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#showfilelist').offset().top - 5 });
    });
}
```

**Default upload.php from plupload:**

```
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
//$targetDir = 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');


// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($in);
        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}


// Return JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

?>
```

Comment: you can get the file size on the php size just with `$_FILES` variable to be more precis `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried that but I want to just pass the text string so that it has been prior calculated